# Is getting a second masters frowned upon?

Tags: masters, second-degree

I recently read on stack overflow that getting two PhDs just shows that you're unfocused and you don't know what you want to do. However, I'm at a small school with a 5 year Computer Engineering bachelors/masters program I feel like I should take advantage of, but I'd also like to go on to do another part time grad degree in the same field or Computer Science at a larger, better established school, while I work.

If I went to a larger school like University of Illnois or MIT or similar, will having a masters and going back for another be frowned upon, or is this a non-issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it is going to help your career much, so I would only recommend to do it if you enjoy the classes.

- I have never seen a job asking for two Masters. If any employer would be impressed by two Masters, it would be because they are in different disciplines. (e.g., a Masters in CS and a Masters in Finance might look good if you are trying to get a particular position at a financial company)
- Two CS Masters is redundant. The only time I have seen this is when a PhD program gives a MS *en route* to a PhD and the student already had a MS.
- Industry is going to value experience over multiple Masters

If you do just enjoy the classes, you might think about a different field that still interests you and is relevant to your day job (e.g., HCI or math).

Or you may just want to look into a PhD program :)

**EDIT:** According to the responses to this very similar qeustion, [Can a masters student apply for a second masters in the same field at another university?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11617/746), it appears that a lot of schools may not even accept a Masters student that already has a Masters in the same field.

Comment: It's not about having 2 masters, really, its more about getting a Masters from a larger school that is better known and more competitive. I've read that the salary increase for a PhD is not worth the time you spend there, but maybe it is if you already are starting with a Masters.

Comment: @JFA The goal of a PhD isn't to get a salary increase, it is getting a job that would be not possible with a Masters (i.e., faculty and research positions).

Comment: @JFA According to that link, those larger or more competitive schools may not accept you since you will already have a Masters.

Comment: In particular, Illinois will _not_ admit you to a Masters program in X if you already have a Masters degree in X.

Comment: Ok I understand, so if I go and get a degree in Y, this is a non-issue. The real underlying question here is, if I got a Masters from two different schools, are people going to look at this and say this candidate is unfocused? That's really the crux of the question.

Comment: @JFA Going to multiple schools for different degrees is generally encouraged. No one would ever call you unfocused for that.

Comment: I guess you answered the question in that getting a masters in two complementary fields is helpful, like CompE and CS

Comment: @JFA No, I would say that is not helpful and is almost always unnecessary.

Comment: I don't see how getting a masters from a better known school wouldn't be helpful I guess.

Comment: It would be. Don't get a master's from your first school then.

Comment: +1 for _"Industry is going to value experience over multiple Masters"_.