# Can I get a second masters in the same subject but with a different focus?

Tags: masters, economics, second-degree

I'm doing a ma in economics which isn't very technical. It's focused on macro and international economics. Once I finish this program I'm going to try to apply to another program for an ma in economics that is more technical with a focus in micro and econometrics. I'd be doing this to broaden my knowledge base in the subject and then teach undergrad for a few years. I could maybe pursue a phd if my employer decided to sponsor me for one. Is this something the second university would allow? How would that be viewed? Would it be suitable if my first degree was a ma in Econ but my second degree was something like an ma in quantitative economics? Perhaps a duel degree in Econ and finance/applied math?

Comment: The answer to this question is almost certainly "you _can_ -- but is it a good thing for you to do so?". Having a masters' degree makes you very qualified to get one, and so you're very likely to get a place on the course. However, what does it get you? Part of high-level education is learning how to effectively teach yourself. Do you want the piece of paper itself, or do you want to understand micro-economics?

Comment: I was considering the same thing. I'm not sure that I could effectively teach myself all of the stuff I'd be learning in the second program. I do like learning Econ topics and as long as my employer is subsidizing a portion of the cost I see no harm in getting the degree/paper. Thanks for replying. I'm still pondering some self study with the MIT freeware and some textbooks I can buy. You've gotten me thinking again!

Comment: Not at my university, you can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate (definitely related): http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11617/2692

Comment: You should probably also re-think planning to teach economics with only a terminal master's degree as a credential, at least if you're in the US. With only a master's degree, you're only likely to find work teaching courses as an adjunct, which pays very poorly.